# Java LocalDateTime minusYears for floating number of years

Tags: java, datetime, floating-point, localdate

Java LocalDateTime `minusYears` takes long argument. In case, if I want to minus floating number of year eg. 2.5 years, how can I do that?

Is there any in-built support?

Note: I take both value and unit as input from the user. The above question is bit of generalization (I have same problem with respect to hours, years, weeks etc.). Sometime it can be 2.7 hours or 2.8 years or 5.3 weeks etc

Comment: Use minusYears(2).minusMonths(6).

Comment: @Wow: Thanks! I get these values as input. 2.5 (2 years and 6 months) is easy case, but in case if someone gives 2.7 or 2.8 then I feel the manual conversion will be cumbersome.

Comment: The question is, how you can difference between the input, for example if the user enter *2.7 hours or 2.8 years or 5.3 weeks* ?

Comment: @YCF_L: That I am able to figure out. I get date, float value and unit as input

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
double years = 2.5;
long months = (long) (years * 12);// 30 month
LocalDateTime ld = LocalDateTime.now();
ld = ld.minusMonths(months);
```

But Note this can lose some days for example if you have :

```
years = 2.7
=>years * 12 > 32.400000000000006
```

so here you can lose `0.400000000000006` month.

So maybe if you round it, it can be more helpful :

```
long months = Math.round(years * 12);
```

---

Edit :

based on your comment :

> Actually I take both value and unit as input. The above question is
>   bit of generalization. Sometime it can be 2.7 hours or 2.8 years or
>   5.3 weeks etc

I think you need something like this :

But be careful with months

```
public static LocalDateTime changeDate(LocalDateTime date, float time, String unit) {
    long newTime;
    switch (unit) {
        case ("hour"):
            newTime = Math.round(time * 60);
            date = date.minusMinutes(newTime);// If hours then subtract minutes
            break;
        case ("day"):
            newTime = Math.round(time * 24);
            date = date.minusHours(newTime);// If days then subtract hours
            break;
        case ("week"):
            newTime = Math.round(time * 7);
            date = date.minusDays(newTime);// If week then subtract days
            break;
        case ("month"):
            newTime = Math.round(time * 30);// here You have to check again
            date = date.minusDays(newTime);// If month then subtract days
            break;
        case ("year"):
            newTime = Math.round(time * 12);
            date = date.minusMonths(newTime);// If days then subtract months
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Actually I take both value and unit as input. The above question is bit of generalization. Sometime it can be 2.7 hours or 2.8 years or 5.3 weeks etc.

Comment: @Abhinav from where you get the data? from database?

Comment: My method takes date, float value and unit as input

Comment: @YCF_L It seems the simpler way :)

Comment: You should replace `String unit` by `ChronoUnit unit` and update the cases. I though updating my answer to make it more generic but not the time right now :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any built-in support for that but you can do that easily by converting the `year` value in month (`* 12`):

```
float year = 2.5F;
LocalDateTime dateTime = dateTime.minusMonths((int)(year * 12);
```

And you can also create a util method if required:

```
public static LocalDateTime removeYear(LocalDateTime dateTime, float year) {
    int monthToRemove = (int)(year * 12);
    return dateTime.minusMonths(monthToRemove);
}
```

By testing it with :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime date = removeYear(LocalDateTime.now(), 2.5F);
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Output :

> 2016-01-31T16:33:26.755

Note that to make the method more robust you could check that `year` represent a float that accept only some kinds of values such as zero for the fractional part (`2.0`) or some fractional such as `0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise both the [minusYears](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minusYears-long-) and [minusMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#minusMonths-long-) methods to do the job.

example:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime result = dateTime.minusYears(2).minusMonths(6);
```

When you say "2.5" years I am assuming you mean "two years and a half" as opposed to "two years and 5 months" but yeah you can correct that anyway if need be.

Comment: Thanks! I get these values as input. 2.5 (2 years and 6 months) is easy case, but in case if someone gives 2.7 or 2.8 then I feel the manual conversion will be cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in support, but you can do this, if you want to sacrifice precision:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2015, 12, 1);
    System.out.println(minusFpYears(ld, 2.5f));
}
static LocalDate minusFpYears(LocalDate ld, float fpyears) {
    float fpmonths = fpyears % 1;
    long years = (long)(fpyears - fpmonths);
    long months = (long)(12L * fpmonths);
    return ld.minusYears(years).minusMonths(months);
}
```

> Thanks for the code! Actually I take both value and unit as input. The
>   above question is bit of generalization. Sometime it can be 2.7 hours
>   or 2.8 years or 5.3 weeks etc.

Make `LocalDate minusFpWeeks(LocalDate ld, float fpweeks)`, `LocalDateTime minusFpHours(LocalDateTime ld, float fphours)` etc functions, to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the code! Actually I take both value and unit as input. The above question is bit of generalization. Sometime it can be 2.7 hours or 2.8 years or 5.3 weeks etc.

Comment: @Abhinav you can handle each of those cases accordingly, using minusWeeks, minusHours, etc functions, I am not going to write everything out for you. For hours, you'd have to use LocalDateTime.

Comment: Thanks! If there is no other option then I will write similar code for all function

Comment: @Abhinav yep, I can't suggest anything else.